# controlling space after a bullet in an unordered list

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to make the text after a bullet in a ul further away?

The only way I can think of is to make a custom bullet image and change the padding, but I was hoping for a more simple resolution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `padding-left`:

```
li { padding-left: 20px }
```

That will move the list item 20 pixels to the right, but it won't move the bullet itself. Here's an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CdmpB/).

Comment: You're welcome :) However, please note that @b01 is right in that if you do change the `list-style-position` somewhere else in your CSS, this will only work when it's set to `outside`.

Comment: Doesn't work if you are using `list-style-position: inside` because the bullet is part of the text block now.

Answer (score 1):

**try this:**

```
<ul>
    <li style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 100px;">line 1</li>
    <li>line 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding to the left on the li tag, but this requires the li list-style-position to be set to outside.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            li {
                list-style-position: outside;
                padding-left: 20px
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <ul>
            <li>Text 1</li>
            <li>Text 2</li>
            <li>Text 3</li>
            <li>Text 4</li>
        </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The default value of `list-style-position` is `outside` so you shouldn't need to specify it (unless, of course, it's overridden elsewhere).